# Como atualizar o sobrenome de uma pessoa que começa com a inicial 'Fabio%'?

Tags: sql, sql-server

É possível fazer isso, eu tenho um nome de uma pessoa que é 'Fábio Mello'
e quero atualizar o nome que começa com 'Fábio%' para ter o sobrenome '%Borges' como faço essa consulta?

```
update pessoa set nome = '%Borges' where nome = 'Fabio%'
```

Essa clásula atualiza o nome da pessoa de forma errada, pois ele inclui o caractere '%'
Ops, eu não expliquei que o 'Mello' teria que sumir.

Comment: Você citou varios bancos diferentes, quer a resposta em todos?

Comment: não, eu citei vários bancos para ver se a reposta chegava mais rápida. É errado?

Comment: Com certeza! Tente focar apenas no banco que está usando, fica mais fácil obter uma resposta precisa para o seu problema.

Comment: pq me deram um -1? O que eu fiz de errado?

Comment: Seria interessante explicarem o -1 mesmo, a pergunta está direta quando ao problema enfrentado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um alternativa que troca só o "Mello":

```
UPDATE pessoa SET nome = REPLACE(nome, 'Mello', 'Borges' ) WHERE nome LIKE 'Fabio'
```

Note que estou apenas demonstrando o `REPLACE`. Paro o caso da pergunta (que não me parece bem formulada, por sinal), não faz o mínimo sentido complicar tanto, nem usar `LIKE` (na verdade, nao testei o `LIKE` no T-SQL).

O ideal nesses casos é colocar os valores literalmente (por o nome completo, e nada de % ) no `WHERE` e no `REPLACE`.

Comment: A sua é a mais adequada, agora que vi que minha resposta adiciona mas não substitui o trecho que ela quer. De qualquer forma valeu o aprendizado , não conhecia o replace, já estava pensando em regex aqui  :)

Comment: Rapaz...ficou diferente...Eu testei aqui com outro exemplo tipo: Fábio Souza Mello e o certo seria virar Fábio Souza Borges mas ele exclue o Fábio e o Souza e fica só 'Borges'...

Comment: Acho que não tem como fazer isso não.

Comment: O mais fácil mesmo é ter o campo sobrenome e nome. Isso caiu em um teste de seleção. Aí vim consultar.

Comment: ´@AlineGonzaga se você tirar a clausula do where, funciona perfeitamente, só que todo nome na sua tabela que tiver "Mello", será substuido para "Borges".

Comment: @AlineGonzaga Não faz o mínimo sentido isso que você disse de excluir o Souza. O Replace que eu pus só troca o Mello, e não mexe no resto.

Comment: @Bacco de fato, testei novamente do jeito que a Aline disse, e funcionou normal.http://i.imgur.com/ybIJlx0.png

Comment: @DiegoF na verdade eu só respondi pra mostrar o replace. Não faz o mínimo sentido usar LIKE pro problema apresentado.

Comment: Vou testar de novo.

Comment: FUNCIONOU! obrigada funcionou.

Comment: Mas o meu funcionou utilizando o % no Fábio e o like.

Comment: Poxa, perfeito o uso do replace, agora só preciso memorizar como escrever ele.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que utiizar:

```
UPDATE pessoa SET nome = 'Fábio Borges' WHERE nome LIKE 'Fábio%';
```

`nome = '%Borges'` faz o nome se tornar literalmente "%Borges", porque o caracter `%` só funciona para fazer match com qualquer coisa na cláusula `where`.